# How can I take a text file and roll every 5 words (or blanks) into one line?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a large text file that looks similar to this

```
Model
            
Series
            
Type
            
MY
            
ProdCode
          
          
            
              
C 600 LEATHER X
              
K96
              
              
2065
              
0132
            
          
            
              
C 600 SUEDE US
              
K64
              
              
2085
              
0132
            
          
            
              
C 650 FAKE US
              
K91
              
              
2055
              
0134


52I Swift White
              
F56
              
X20
              
2235
              
3C93
```

How can I convert this into a CSV file that looks like this?

```
Model,Series,Type,MY,ProdCode
C600 LEATHER X,K96, ,2065,0132
C600 SUEDE US,K64, ,2085,0132
C 650 FAKE US,K91, ,2055,1034
52I Swift White,F56,X20,2235,3C93
```

I'm struggling to defeat the items that are blanks. The code below causes the alignment of the fields to the headers to be off by one and causes the overall row to be misaligned.

I tried this piece of code below and can't seem to find a workaround. Any help is appreciated to fix the alignment properly here.

```
with open('output.txt') as file:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in file]

item_count = 0
current_line = ""

for item in lines:
    if item != "":
        current_line = current_line + ", " + item
        item_count = item_count + 1

        if item_count == 5:
            item_count = 0
            print(current_line)
            current_line = ""
```

Comment: What if `Model` and `Series` fields in either block  are both empty?

Comment: Those should never be blank. But if it were to happen, then they should just be blank items in the row.

Comment: But, first, try to recognize them in that case

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following you ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the format of your data, but from what I observed, each group has five fields, separated by blank lines.

In each group, every other line is a data line, so the max number of lines for each group is nine, and if any field is blank, that line is not there, so you have consecutive blank lines.

So the following code should work:

```py
from pathlib import Path

lines = [i.strip() for i in Path('output.txt').read_text().splitlines()]

l = len(lines)
i = 0
data = []

while i != l:
    if not lines[i]:
        i += 1
        continue
    d = min(9, l - i)
    group = lines[i:i+d].copy()
    entry = []
    while group:
        field = group.pop(0)
        entry.append(field)
        if field and group:
            group.pop(0)
    data.append(entry)
    i += d
```

---

### Update

I have fixed a small bug that caused `IndexError: pop from empty list`. Now it is working as intended.

When I wrote the answer, I wasn't able to test it properly, and I couldn't find the opportunity to test the code until now.

The output is this:

```
[['Model', 'Series', 'Type', 'MY', 'ProdCode'],
 ['C 600 LEATHER X', 'K96', '', '2065', '0132'],
 ['C 600 SUEDE US', 'K64', '', '2085', '0132'],
 ['C 650 FAKE US', 'K91', '', '2055', '0134'],
 ['52I Swift White', 'F56', 'X20', '2235', '3C93']]
```

If you absolutely want csv, I strongly discourage you from doing so, you can do this:

```
'\n'.join(', '.join(f'"{s}"' for s in e) for e in data)
```

Output:

```
In [10]: print('\n'.join(', '.join(f'"{s}"' for s in e) for e in data))
"Model", "Series", "Type", "MY", "ProdCode"
"C 600 LEATHER X", "K96", "", "2065", "0132"
"C 600 SUEDE US", "K64", "", "2085", "0132"
"C 650 FAKE US", "K91", "", "2055", "0134"
"52I Swift White", "F56", "X20", "2235", "3C93"
```

But I guess you actually wanted something like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple

car = namedtuple('car', data[0])
cars = [car(*i) for i in data[1:]]
```

```
In [16]: cars
Out[16]:
[car(Model='C 600 LEATHER X', Series='K96', Type='', MY='2065', ProdCode='0132'),
 car(Model='C 600 SUEDE US', Series='K64', Type='', MY='2085', ProdCode='0132'),
 car(Model='C 650 FAKE US', Series='K91', Type='', MY='2055', ProdCode='0134'),
 car(Model='52I Swift White', Series='F56', Type='X20', MY='2235', ProdCode='3C93')]
```

But actually it's best to do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

cars_df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
```

Output:

```
In [21]: print(cars_df)
             Model Series Type    MY ProdCode
0  C 600 LEATHER X    K96       2065     0132
1   C 600 SUEDE US    K64       2085     0132
2    C 650 FAKE US    K91       2055     0134
3  52I Swift White    F56  X20  2235     3C93
```

Comment: You are correct about each group having 5 fields, however the number of lines between each group can vary and isn't always 9 unfortunately.